# Difference between "WOULD" and "WILL"................?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Consider the examples:-

```
When would I get the access of the system.
When will I get the access of the system.
```

which sentence is correct in spoken/written English.

thanks.

Comment: No difference in meaning.  The use of would is more  politte and less direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When would I get access *to* the system.**

We're talking about an event in the future that may or may not happen. It's still conditional. Maybe asked during a job interview.

**When will I get access *to* the system.**

This is a thing that is going to happen, it's just a matter of time.

Things to note: it's "**to** the system" in either case.
Each would be correct to their respective circumstances.

Comment: In the situation where one has the right to access the system, but you have to wait for some action to occur first, you could use either one. In asking this question, *would* is more polite and indirect than *will*, which is more demanding.

Comment: @user3169 in that situation I'd always use *will*, *would* might seem more polite but it's actually incorrect.