# "would" can be used to express the degree of certainty? Or it is always used under hypothetical condition?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would, modality

I am wondering about "would" can be also used to express the degree of certainty.
Not any website shows any example sentences using "would" to express the degree of certainty only except for the under website.
https://medium.com/@gmbley/modal-verbs-levels-of-certainty-ba14047dd134
This site only shows "would".

Anyway, I have also read this previous Q & A ([Would vs will degree of certainty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110752/would-vs-will-degree-of-certainty)),

According to this, "Would" is only used under hypothetical conditional sentence like Type 2 conditional sentence?

If yes, the under-mentioned sentences using "would" are also under hypothetical conditional sentences???
[image]
[image]
[image]

FYI: Those example sentences are from Collins, Macmilland, and Longman dictionary.

Comment: In contexts like *You wouldn't know him, That would have been her car,* using the modal ***would*** is really just a convention that [arguably] slightly "softens" an assertion and/or "distances" the speaker from the words. Often, all it conveys is something along the likes of *It's really too trivial to bother mentioning or even thinking about, but if we **did** want to consider the matter, **we would discover / agree** [that you don't know him / that it was her car].*

Comment: Would does carry some degree of probability, but it is so close to certainty that it functions more as a social nicety. It also expresses incredulity -- compare: "Why did anyone want to kill..." vs "Why would anyone want to kill..." It is a touch more formal and thus can be more serious or weighty.

Comment: @FeliniusRex /// Hi, that usage of "would" is kind of being convention, right? However technically speaking that usage also stems from Type 2 conditional sentence? In this case, the nuance is different to the basic form of Type 2 conditional.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica /// Usually Type 2 conditional sentence express the contrary & unreal condition to real fact and the possible result(consequence) which is also contrary to the real fact. But these case do not always depict the contrary ones. Instead it is for softening assertion, for distances and social nicety. Do I understand exactly?

Comment: Nobody when speaking thinks, "Oh, I want to use a type 2 conditional sentence here." They just express incredulity or distance themselves slightly from the action. It's not about logic -- it's about finding the tool to communicate the information or the emotion.

Examples: Why would anyone want to kill Suzie? How would you even do that? I wouldn't do that, if I were you. Why would Raymond kill Mrs. Peacock in the dining room, with the knife?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Thank for your precious advice. So I can simply think "would" is used to express politeness(=social nicety) or incredulity or distancing such as certainty and guessing. In the case of distancing, the degree/level of would is less stronger than will or other modal verbs like Must, Can and Shall.

Comment: @Tae-Bbong-E Yes, you've got it. :)